# I'm looking for a good Coup de Grace weapon for my sneaky dude for when he needs to get up close and personal with someone, any suggestions?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, dnd-3e, critical-hit

Of particular interest are weapons that can be used one-handed, hidden relatively well, and are light, but I'll take a look at everything that's suggested.  Weapon proficiency is not a problem for me in this since I don't intend to use it for much else besides Coup de Grace.

Right now I'm looking for things with an x4 or higher crit on their own, or anything I can make Mercurial for an x4 or higher crit.  Heck, if anyone finds a long, straight blade with d6 or higher dmg and an x4 crit that I can make mercurial for an x6 I'd love you forever.

While my GM has for the most part banned Dragon Magazine material, mention it as well if you know something good from it because I might be able to convince him for a single weapon.

3.0 and 3.5 material is allowed by the way.

PS/Bonus Points: A buddy of mine mentioned seeing a one-handed scythe somewhere, what are the stats on that?  Is it an x4 crit?  I can't seem to find it anywhere and he forgot where he saw it.

Comment: One handed scythe, unfortunately is called either a kama or a sickle and is 1d6/x2 slashing. However, does your GM allow mercurial property on weapons that are not straight blades? Say, one could reasonably think of having a quicksilver bulb in blunt weapon shaft, thus making a Light pick 1d4/x4 -> 1d4/x6.

Comment: He tends to lean towards RAW, but he has made allowances here and there.  I'd have to ask, but it's worth a shot at least, thanks for the idea :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enjoy the absurdly-named exotic weapon, the

## Dragonsplit

Appearing the *Monster Manual IV* in the Greenspawn Sneak entry, the dragonsplit

> can be used as a piercing weapon like a short sword. Alternative grips use its long edge for
>   slashing attacks or its short edge for chopping and hacking. It counts as a light weapon for the purpose of Two-Weapon Fighting and Weapon Finesse. (151).

A Medium wielder employing this 2-lb. otherwise-one-handed<sup>1</sup> exotic weapon can choose, before making an attack, to inflict *either* 1d6 points of piercing damage with an 18-20 threat range *or* 1d6 points of slashing damage with a ×4 critical multiplier. It's for *D&D 3.5* but, strangely, no price is given for purchasing one.

I always imagine the dragonsplit looking like an oversized [balisong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_knife), although the official depiction is far different. (The greenspwan sneak on *MM4* 149 is wielding one; it's just a weird-shaped blade.) Picturing it as a big butterfly knife is the only way I can make the dumb name acceptable in my head.

---

1. Yeah, I *know*. So, if one is so inclined, with it one can use the feat Power Attack (*PH* 98).

Comment: Huh, I always imagined it as a tonfa with too many blades, for some reason.

Comment: (*actually looks up the picture*) I suppose I imagined it as a tonfa with too many blades because that’s more-or-less what’s depicted.

Comment: I like it, I will have to investigate this and see what I can work out.

Comment: Took a gander, looks unnecessarily outrageous, which makes it just right.  I've never seen anything that specifically bans short swords from being mercurial, but the wording does seem to hint that it should be left to long sword and such.  Anyone ever seen someone mention mercurial short swords?  If that's viable enough, then I suppose a mercurial dragonsplit isn't far off.

Comment: @Dorian Consider asking another question about type restrictions for Mercurial weapons.

Comment: @Lilienthal the thing is the type restrictions for those would vary from DM to DM simply due to the lack of an actual material entry.  IIRC the RAW of the Mercirual weapons alluded to it working for straight-bladed weapons.  Otherwise, if the DM doesn't want to allow anything but RAW regardless there would only be the three allowed period.

Answer (score 7):

Try the Gnome Battlepick, an exotic weapon from the Arms and Equipment Guide. 1d6 damage, 4x crit.

The Arms and Equipment Guide being a 3.0 book, it is listed as a "small" weapon.

Answer (score 4):

## Core: Light Pick

The light pick is a 1d4 damage, 20 crit, ×4 multiplier light martial weapon. Weighs 3 lbs, costs 4 gp. 4d4 averages only 10 damage, but if you have, say, 14 Strength that’s 4d4+8 for 18, plus your Sneak Attack damage whatever it is, for a pretty nasty Fort save. Not much is surviving that regularly. And that’s ignoring Craven, which you really *should* have; that would give you 4× your character level on top of that.

The dragonsplit is much better for a general-purpose weapon, though rogues rarely have the feat to spare. I like the light pick as just something to have available just for coup de grace. I would probably not even bother putting magic on it until pretty high level (a *+1 [collision](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/items/weapons.htm#collision) light pick* would be choice there, +24 coup de grace damage for a +3-equivalent), and wouldn’t use it as my primary weapon on most rogues since they don’t have proficiency with it and it’s not worth *getting* proficiency with it.

Comment: Hah, for some reason I mentally had the picks down as x3 weapons. Oops.

Comment: I can't be alone in *hating* rolling d4s.

Comment: @Ernir Yeah, for whatever reason the scythe is basically treated as a *really big* pick. Which, I guess, kind of makes sense? Similar shape, both are really tools not weapons?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I have never in my life actually rolled a physical d4.

Comment: You don't hate d4s until you've stepped on one.